# Existence and uniqueness of solution of Diophantine equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,d_1$ be known positive integers. Let $x$ be an unknown satisfying
$$ 4(a_1d_1+1) \mid (a_1x+d_1a_2)^2$$
$$ 4(b_1d_1+1) \mid (b_1x+d_1b_2)^2$$
$$ 4(c_1d_1+1) \mid (c_1x+d_1c_2)^2.$$

Where, the integers $a_1,b_1,c_1$ and $d_1$ are distinct.
I want to know whether solution exist, if so is it unique?

I think if solution exists, it can not be unique. Suppose $x=d$ is a solution, then so is $d+4k(a_1d_1+1)(b_1d_1+1)(c_1d_1+1)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

In my view, solution need not always exist.

For example if $a~|~bx+c$ then $bx+c = ka$ which means $x = \frac{ka-c}{b}$ which need not always be an integer.

Thus I am curious to know under what condition does the solution exists for the above system?

Comment: Given the placement of the variables, I'm guessing there's some more context behind this. Could you give us some of that context, and tell us what you've already tried?

Comment: Also: are the known natural numbers $a_1, a_2,$ etc, required to be distinct from one another, or distinct partially? If not, there's a trivial-ish solution for $d=3$, all other variables $=1$, and $x=1$ as the solution.

Comment: @Eric Snyder, every variable except $x$ is known. I just want to know whether always such $x$ exists.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the other variables are known. But are they required to be distinct? And/or are there any other constraints on those variables? Or are you merely looking for solutions in terms of those variables, with no other constraints? As to your edit: I'm also inclined to think unique solutions are unlikely, just because of the periodic nature of divisibility.

Comment: @Eric Snyder, Thank you for pointing it out. The integers $a_1,b_1,c_1$ and $d_1$ are distinct, there is no restriction on other variables.

Comment: Quick thought: consider the expressions in parens on the RHS, i.e., $a_1 x +d_1 a_2$. Each has four variables. Either all are odd, or at least two are even, because the expression must be even. If exactly two are even, they must be in separate multiplications. So, for instance,  if $a_1, a_2, d_1$ are all odd, then all solutions have $x$ odd. If exactly one of the three is even, all solutions will have either $x$ even, unless if the only even one is $a_1$, in which case there will be no solutions.

Comment: @Eric Snyder, thank you, yes that's right.